# Getting events from database that spans multiple days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all events of a calendar stored in a database table which are inside a specific range given by the user. It works until the event spans multiple days. At that point the end date will not be in the time range and so the query will discard it. My question is how to get all the events that fall inside the given range, no matter if they start before the range and ends inside it or if they start inside the range and end after. I must exclude from the results all the events that starts after the range or ends before the range

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `start` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `end` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The current query

```
SELECT t0_.name AS name0, t0_.start AS start3, t0_.end AS end4 
  FROM events t0_ 
  WHERE t0_.start > start
    AND t0_.end < end
```

Example data:

```
name                     start                    end
--------------------     --------------------     --------------------
test event               2012-02-17 09:00:00      2012-02-17 09:50:00
test event2              2012-02-17 09:00:00      2012-02-19 09:00:00
test event3              2012-02-12 09:00:00      2012-02-17 09:00:00
test event4              2012-02-12 09:00:00      2012-02-13 09:00:00
```

Expected result data:

```
name                     start                    end
--------------------     --------------------     --------------------
test event               2012-02-17 09:00:00      2012-02-17 09:50:00
test event2              2012-02-17 09:00:00      2012-02-19 09:00:00
test event3              2012-02-12 09:00:00      2012-02-17 09:00:00
```

With range:

```
2012-02-17 00:00:00 - 2012-02-17 23:59:59
```

as you can see I take the events that are inside the given range, plus the events that starts in the range and end after and the events that start before the range but ends inside it.

Comment: Have you tried using BETWEEN?  start BETWEEN date1 AND date2 OR end BETWEEN date1 AND date2

Comment: Be careful with `<` ,`>`, `<=`, `>=`, and `BETWEEN` when doing date selection. I think you need `<=` and `>=` in your query, the way it's cast.

Comment: Can you explain your desired search criteria in more detail?  What is supposed to happen with a multi-day event?  If any of the days of the multi day event is in the range you search for, is it supposed to be found?  What does "day" mean -- midnight -to- midnight? Or the 24-hour period starting at the time the event starts?  Suggest you write out several examples with an explanation of why they should be either included or excluded.

Comment: @Ollie you got the point and explained it better than me: given a range the query is supposed to find all the events that fall inside it, no matter if they start and end inside it, if they start before and end inside it or if they start inside it and end after. I must exclude the events that start after the given range or ends before the range

Comment: @Steffano so my solution is just what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple way is to do it by negation:

```
SELECT t0_.name AS name0, t0_.start AS start3, t0_.end AS end4 
FROM events t0_ 
WHERE 
    NOT(
        t0_.end < '2013-09-05 00:00:00'
        OR t0_.start > '2013-09-06 23:59:59'
    )
```

That way you filter out all events that end before range and start after range.

Comment: why do you use 2013-09-06 23:59:59 instead of 2013-09-05 23:59:59?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it was the end date in your question between some edits.

Comment: the query seems to work, thank you. I don't know how I couldn't think it myself

Comment: This where condition does exactly what you wrote: `I must exclude the events that start after the given range or ends before the range`